# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. running npm.cmd works however

Tags: node.js, npm

Been at this for hours, for some reason `npm` suddenly broke, was working yesterday without issues but today it throws me this error, I have messed with path and read through any help article on this issue but all of them don't seem to fix the issue. I've updated (was on 14.x.x and updated to the latest version of 14.x.x). uninstalled/reinstalled, all to no change. Running `npm.cmd` or `npx.cmd` works, but runs into issues when installing any package as it tries to run `npm` rather then `npm.cmd` while installing. In the command prompt `node` works perfectly, I can run `node -v` etc without issues, just npm and npx seem to be broken. As for some extra info `C:\Users\NameHere\AppData\Roaming\npm` exists as well as `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. In the user path variables `C:\Users\NameHere\AppData\Roaming\npm` exists, and in the system path variables `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` exists (I've also tried adding the path above to the system variables, as well as restarting the computer after each of these changes).

All I can think of is that some program is causing this but even then I'm not sure how it could be, or what would've changed from yesterday to today.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, went back to the environment variables, and under `system variables > PATHTXT` I added `;.cmd`